# Why can the answer not be "if"? ___ the government in Greece postpone

Tags: conditional-constructions, exam-questions, inversion

> ____ the government in Greece postpone the debts of farmers, they can cope with the economic difficulties.
>
> a. could
>   b. should
>   c. only if
>   d. if
>   e. even if

Why is answer "d" (if) not correct?

Answer (score 3):

"the government in Greece" is a singular noun, and so takes singular conjugations (at least in American English; it's a bit different in British English). The present indicative singular third person of "postpone" is "postpones". This leads to the conclusion that "postpone" is not indicative, but instead subjunctive. "should", but not "if", takes the subjunctive, so I would expect that to be listed as the correct answer. Although I think that it should be

> Should the government in Greece postpone the debts of farmers, they will be able to cope with the economic diffuculties.

Comment: -1 'should' doed not "take the subjunctive." The construction *should* + bare infinitive can form a subjunctive construction.

Comment: But in British English, it certainly can be _if_.

Comment: @Clare You seem be saying that rather than the subjunctive being a grammatical form that happens to be the same as the bare infinitive, there is no subjunctive form at all, and the infinitive form is used to indicate the subjunctive mood. This seems like a matter of nomenclature rather than actual grammar, and the fact that other languages have a distinct subjunctive form suggests that treating "postpone" to be a subjunctive form that, in English, happens to be the same as the infinitive is the most useful analysis.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155893/how-is-the-english-subjunctive-composed#156416 may or may not interest you. Most of today's linguists do not regard English as having sujunctive forms (inflections); even the *were* in *if I were you* is not a subjunctive form but called the *irrealis were*.

Comment: The question shows postpone without an s. Should x postpone does not take an s.

Comment: +1 for noting the awkwardness of "should ... can ..."

Comment: @Lambie Is that directed at me?

Comment: Should x postpone something is modal. There is no subjunctive at all here.

Answer (score 2):

**Should** the government in Greece **postpone** the debts of farmers, they can cope with the economic difficulties.

**should postpone**, without an s, should + infinitive. The should is modal here and does not take an s. But the meaning is in the event.

should, could postpone, no s. But could does not work here. It would have to be a question: Could the government postpone, etc. or: The government could postpone [in the declarative]

**If** (or even if or only if) the government in Greece postpone**s** the debts of farmers, they can cope with the economic difficulties.

**postpones, with an s can take if, only if and even if.**

if, only if, even if=postpones with an s.

Please note: **Should the government postpone** means **in the event of**. Should postpone, no s. It is not meaning of should + infinitive which is a duty or obligation as in: I should go now.

The right answer is should.

Should you leave early, I won't see you.